# htaccess and folders does it affect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i have folders and another php files with an id.
What i want to do is to be able to view those php files in the following format:  **www.website.com/cakedetails** in the browser url and site-wide rather than www.website.com/cakes.php?id=chocolate-cake

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/([a-z.*0-9_-]+)/$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/cakes.php?id=$1
```

i managed to put the above in my htaccess file, but so far to no avail. the first part of the code converts to www. if it does not have that prefix, and the second part of the code to gather the cake details.

Can you tell me if the above code is correct, as im no expert in htaccess language and i cannot get the above code to work.

Your input is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have stuff like this: `http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/` in your rule's regex. The string that the regex matches against doesn't include the protocol/domain name, **just** the URI, so just the `/cakedetails` part.

Problem with that is you don't want to blindly match everything, so you need some conditions to make sure someone's not requesting an existing file.

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /cakes.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```